# how to append json variable as child nodes using "jstree" jquery plugin - no ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jstree

I have a jsTree using the json data format. 
Loading the root nodeset is fine.

My problem is how to append child nodes to the parent node that was clicked.

ANY help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    $("#tree-cat1")
    .bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
        console.log(data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));
        //eval(loadChild());
        //at this point i need to append the result of loadChild() to the tree under the relevant node
    })
    .jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "data": eval(loadRoot())
        },
        "themes": {"theme": "classic","dots": true,"icons": true},
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
    })

function loadRoot() {
    return "[{'data':'A node','state':'closed','attr':{'id':'A'}}]";
}
function loadChild() {
    return "[{'data':'A1 node','attr':{'id':'A1'}}]";
}
```

Comment: do you want to add children each time the node will be opened? why you don't use 'children' property to append items on tree initialization

Comment: each time node expands i run oracle query to get data (all within javascript). Data returned into a js variable. i then have to populate tree with returned data at the relevant point in tree (as per the code sample)

Answer (score 2):

see documentation here: [jsTree docu](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)

*EDIT*

here is the code, you need to change url to your destination, try it

html:

```
<div id="tree-cat1"></div>
```

js:

```
 $("#tree-cat1").jstree({
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
    "themes": {"theme": "classic","dots": true,"icons": true},
    "json_data": {
          //root elements
        "data": [{"data":'A node',"state":'closed',"attr":{"id":'A'}}], 
        "ajax": {
            "type": 'POST',
            "data": {"action": 'getChildren'},
            "url": function (node) { 
                var nodeId = node.attr('id'); //id="A"

                return 'yuorPathTo/GetChildrenScript/' + nodeId;
            },
            "success": function (new_data) {
                //where new_data = node children 
                //e.g.: [{'data':'A1 node','attr':{'id':'A1'}}, {'data':'A2 node','attr':{'id':'A2'}}]
                return new_data;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*OLD PART*
something like that will populate opened node with children, if not already done:

```
 ...
    "json_data": {
          //root elements
        "data": [{"data":'A node',"state":'closed',"attr":{"id":'group_A'}}], 
        "ajax": {
            "type": 'POST',
            "data": {"action": act.GET_GROUPREPORTS},
            "url": function (node) { 
                var nid = node.attr('id'); //id="group_A"
                nid = nid.substr(nid.lastIndexOf('_')+1);

                return module.getDBdata_path + nid;
            },
            "success": function (data) {
                var rid, new_data = data;

                if (typeof data[0] === 'undefined') {
                    new_data = [];
                    for (rid in data) {
                        if(data.hasOwnProperty(rid)) {
                          new_data.push({"data": data[rid], 
                               "attr": {"id": 'rprefix_'+rid, 
                                        "title": ' ', 
                                        "rel": 'report',
                                        "href": module.repView_path+rid
                              }
                          });
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new_data;
            }
        }
    }, ...
```

Comment: Thanks Irishka, but i still cannot get it working. I tried your suggestion using the ajax object but somewhere i'm missing something. If you have time could you use my example as a basis to your solution? If we get this working i would owe you big time!